# call scripts from foreach

Tags: powershell, start-job

I need some help or maybe advise a better way with what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to copy few things so I have

```
$tests = @("test1", "test3", "test5")
$copy_1 = {
$source = "C:\Source\test1"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\test1"

Copy-Item $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Container -Force
}

$copy_2 = {
$source = "C:\Source\test2"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\test2"

 Copy-Item $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Container -Force
}

$copy_3 = {
$source = "C:\Source\test3"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\test3"

Copy-Item $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Container -Force
}

$copy_4 = {
$source = "C:\Source\test4"
$Destination = "C:\Destination\test4"

Copy-Item $Source -Recurse -Destination $Destination -Container -Force
}

Foreach($i in $Tests)
{
    IF($i -eq "test1)
        {
          Start-Job -Name $i -Scriptblock {$($i)}
        }
}

....
```

This doesn't call my scriptblock.

```
      PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  

      BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ($($i))
```

How can I call $test1 block?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish by doing it like that.  This would be much easier.

```
$tests = @("test1", "test3", "test5")

Foreach($i in $Tests)
{
    IF($i -eq "test1")
        {
          Start-Job -Name $i -Scriptblock { Copy-Item "C:\Source\$($i)" "C:\Destination\$($i)" -Recurse -Container -Force }
        }
}

....
```

Edit:

Like I said in the comment below, the code you posted is doing nothing with your copy_1, copy_2, ect variables. All you are doing is iterating through an array of strings. This would work and is closer to the way you're trying to do it. Utilize [PSObjects](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750381.aspx)

```
$copy_1 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$copy_1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Name -value "copy_1"
$copy_1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Source -value "C:\Source\test1"
$copy_1 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Destination -value "C:\Destination\test1"

$copy_2 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$copy_2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Name -value "copy_2"
$copy_2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Source -value "C:\Source\test2"
$copy_2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Destination -value "C:\Destination\test2"

$copy_3 = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$copy_3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Name -value "copy_3"
$copy_3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Source -value "C:\Source\test3"
$copy_3 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name Destination -value "C:\Destination\test3"

$tests = @($copy_1, $copy_2, $copy_3)

Foreach($i in $tests)
{
    if($i.Name -eq "copy_1")
        {
          Start-Job -Name $i.Name -Scriptblock { Copy-Item $i.Source $i.Destination -recurse -Container -Force }          
        }
}
```

Comment: why do `$($i)` instead of just `$i` ?

Comment: I was thinking the same as Mike. I think just `$i` would do it there. But to make the code look cleaner (I have a lot to copy)I was trying to accomplish the way I was doing it. I'll give this one a try and see what happens. Maybe in the meantime someone else might have an idea.

Comment: I do $($i) inside quotes as a habit, that way the entire variable is evaluated.  It's more handy when using properties inside quotes, such as "$($server.Name)".  If you have "$server.Name" then that is not evaluated the same.

Comment: Also, the code you posted is doing nothing with your copy_1, copy_2, ect variables. All you are doing is iterating through an array of strings.  Not sure if you are aware of that or not.

Comment: Hi Auto,. Thanks for the code. Yes, I know my code wasn't doing anything and that was my initial question. Rather than writing the whole thing in the scriptblock(copy-item ...) I was hoping I could just call the block of the test. for example IF($i -eq $test-1) just call the Test-1 script block in my initial post. However, since it's been a while and there are no other answers, I'll mark yours as the correct one. Thank you for your help.